# How do I bind a WPF Canvas (or similar) to a list of lines

Tags: wpf, canvas, binding, line, observablecollection

I have a `DataGrid` which may contain 1000's of rows. I would like a narrow canvas panel on the side of it that is about 15px wide to show small red/green/blue indicator lines relating to the rows in the `DataGrid`.

Something like :

[image]

Sample problem: I know lines 5, 60, 700 out of 1400 have errors. How do I programmatically set the canvas items as lines whilst also splitting them up so they relate to the seperation in the `DataGrid`. ie. there will be  a big distance between 60 and 700.

I know I can do this with some sort of ratio. I.e. if the height of the canvas is 500, I can do 1400/500 = ratio. Then if I want to plot line 700 I would just divide that by the ratio.

I would like to know how I can :

1. Add lines from the code behind, but even better to bind to some sort
   of `ObservableCollection` of lines.
2. How to specify the height from the top of the `canvas` for each line.

Comment: You might consider using another base control, rather than canvas, something like `ItemsControl` that allows you to add children.  Logically this makes a lot more sense than trying to draw out lots of individual lines and track what they map to.

Comment: @CodingGorilla thanks for your advice, how would I go about making such an itemsControl, what kind of items will it need, and how will it draw those items?

Comment: Those are all complex questions, I can't write the solution for you, but there are tons of articles and blog posts on the internet about this stuff.  Just do a search for "WPF ItemsControl".